# how to login in with database date instead of static data

Tags: .net, typescript

I created my first register login system in dot net and angular through a tutorial, my problem is that in the tutorial the author used static data as you can see in the code below. But i want to use my data from my database, so currently i dont know how i should create a if statement for my database.

```html
 //Login
        [HttpPost("login/")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody]Benutzer user)
        {
            if(user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            if(user.benutzername == "123123" && user.passwort == "123")
            {
                var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"));
                var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken
                (
                    issuer: "http://localhost:5000",
                    audience: "http://localhost:5000",
                    claims: new List<Claim>(),
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
                    signingCredentials: signingCredentials
                );

                var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);
                return Ok(new { Token = tokenString });
            }
            return Unauthorized();
        }
```

My idea is first to search for the user with the username like that:

```html
 var currentUserName = _context.Benutzer.FindAsync(user.benutzername);
```

But after that i dont know how i can get the specific password to compare it.

Comment: run snippet is not showing any thing, i think you will edit your question

Comment: for me it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally deleted all and created a whole new Accountsystem with the help of identity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio